# Element div not allowed as child of element a in this context

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

I try to validate my Website for HTML and the following error came through:
Element div not allowed as child of element a in this context: Does someone find the error here?

```
{%- liquid
  assign img_url = image | img_url: '1x1' | replace: '_1x1.', '_{width}x.'
  assign height = image.height | times: 1.0 | default: 1.0
  assign width = image.width | times: 1.0 | default: 1.0

  assign padding_top = height | divided_by: width | times: 100 | append: "%"

  if id == blank
    assign id = image.id
  endif
-%}

<div class="image js-enabled {% unless disable_style %}image--{{ id }} {% endunless %}{{ wrapper_class }}">
  <img
    class="image__img lazyload{% if preload %} lazypreload{% endif %} {{ image_class }}"
    src="{{ image | img_url: '300x300' }}"
    data-src="{{ img_url }}"
    data-widths="[180, 360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1296, 1512, 1728, 2048]"
    data-aspectratio="{{ image.aspect_ratio }}"
    data-sizes="auto"
    alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}"
  >
</div>

{%- unless disable_style -%}
  <style>
    .image--{{ id }} {
      padding-top: {{ padding_top }};
    }
  </style>
{%- endunless -%}

<noscript>
  <div class="image image--{{ id }} {{ wrapper_class }}">
    <img class="image__img" src="{{ image | img_url: '2048x2048' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
  </div>
</noscript>
```

Comment: I don't see any <a> element in your code, are you sure that is the part giving the error?

Comment: @FabioFilippi yes that's the problem. I don't know why

Comment: Validating HTML and seeing an error in the HTML has nothing to do with presenting some irrelevant Liquid. If you want your question answered, you have to do a better job of isolating where the real problem lies, and showing that here. As Fabio commented, it appears you are not presenting the right code here.

Comment: Please show compiled html